# Is there a linear order with this property

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

I was trying and failing to construct a linear order L each of whose uncountable subsets contains an uncountable well ordered subset but L is not a countable union of well ordered subsets. Is this possible?

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Are you sure that there is one? Where did you get the idea to try and construct such a linear order?

Answer (score 2):

For each countable limit ordinal $\alpha$ choose some $\langle \alpha_n : n < \omega \rangle$ increasing and cofinal in $\alpha$. Then it can be checked that the set $L$ of these sequences ordered lexicographically satisfies your requirements.

Comment: Wait, isn't this just $\omega_1\times\omega$?

Comment: No. No stationary subset of $L$ is a well ordering.

Comment: So I'm not 100% clear as to how you define the order.

Comment: It's the lexic order: $\langle \alpha_n \rangle \prec \langle \beta_n \rangle$ if $\alpha_n < \beta_n$ where $n$ is least such that $\alpha_n \neq \beta_n$.

Comment: Ah, okay, I had a completely different definition in mind.